Mediation with PROCESS - Why is my b-path insignificant but my lm significant?
I´m currently working on my bachelor's thesis and ran a mediation with PROCESS (Model 4). My IV is self-compassion, my DV is general mental health and my mediator is loneliness. I am a little bit confused because my b path is insignificant ($b = 0.12$) in my mediation model, but when I did separate linear models to test the a and b path, because I was interested in the results, I realized that i get nearly the same results for path a but not with path b. The linear model with loneliness as the IV and general mental health as the DV seems to be significant ($b = 0.19*$).
How does that come? It would be great if someone could explain it to me!

Sounds like instead of mediation of self-compassion effect through loneliness, the loneliness effect on mental health is due to the variance loneliness shares with self-compassion, and self-compassion is the construct actually driving the effect. It seems possible the mediation could happen the other way around, self-compassion could mediate the effect of loneliness.
